# MySQL SSH Tunnel with PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, ssh, phpstorm

I'm using the PhpStorm database browser.
I don't want direct access to the 3306 port of my database. Therefore I want to force the users to use SSH Tunnel.

On the server, I configured the MySQL with this user :

```
user1@localhost : SELECT privilege to myDatabase
user1@127.0.0.1 : SELECT privilege to myDatabase (I also tried this)
```

My PhpStorm has 2 tabs for SQL Connection configuration:

First tab is for SQL

```
host : localhost (THIS DOES NOT WORK)
username : user1
port : 3306
database: myDatabase
```

Second tab is for SSH Tunnel

```
host : myserver.com
username : user1 (same username but this one is a SSH one)
port : 22
```

---

This configuration doesn't work but when I change the SQL HOST to `myserver.com` AND when I add a privilege to `user1@%` then it works.

I don't want to add `user1@%` as this allow the user to go directly to my database without using tunnel.

Can you help me with this two host configuration I have to put in PhpStorm ?

Comment: did you try using 127.0.0.1 as the host in the PhpStorm config?

Comment: it only works because you are not using the tunnel, you are connecting straight to the server database which is exposed and you don't want that. I am having same issue and can't make it work :/ Its super simple setup, dunno how could they mess it up so badly. Workaround for me is to make the tunnel in command line and connect afterwards but it is annoying